# Have PowerShell script use C# code, then pass arguments to Main method

Tags: c#, powershell, program-entry-point

I found a technet blog article the said it was possible to have PowerShell use C# code.
Article: [Using CSharp (C#) code in Powershell scripts](http://blogs.technet.com/b/stefan_gossner/archive/2010/05/07/using-csharp-c-code-in-powershell-scripts.aspx)

I found the format I need to get the C# code to work in PowerShell, but if it don't pass the `Main` method an argument (`[namespace.class]::Main(foo)`) the script throws an error.

Is there a way I can pass a string of "on" or "off" to the main method, then depending on which string is passed run an if statement? If this is possible can you provide examples and/or links?

Below is the way I'm currently trying to structure my code.

```
$Assem = @( //assemblies go here)

$source = @"
using ...;

namespace AlertsOnOff
{
    public class onOff
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args )
        {
             if(args == on)
              {//post foo }
             if(arge == off)
              { //post bar }

        }
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source -ReferencedAssumblies $Assem
[AlertsOnOff.onOff]::Main(off)

#PowerShell script code goes here.

[AlertsOnOff.onOff]::Main(on)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well to start, if you are going to compile and run C# code, you need to write valid C# code. On the PowerShell side, if you invoke `Main` from PowerShell, you need to pass it an argument. PowerShell will automatically put a single argument into an array for you, but it won't insert an argument if you don't have one. That said, its not clear why this is in a Main method. It's not an executable. It could very well just have two static methods, `TurnOn` and `TurnOff`. The code below compiles and runs, modify as you see fit:

```
$source = @"
using System;

namespace AlertsOnOff
{
    public class onOff
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
             if(args[0] == `"on`")
             {
                  Console.WriteLine(`"foo`");
             }
             if(args[0] == `"off`")
             { 
                  Console.WriteLine(`"bar`");
             }
        }
    }
}
"@

Add-Type -TypeDefinition $Source
[AlertsOnOff.onOff]::Main("off")

# Other code here

[AlertsOnOff.onOff]::Main("on")
```

Comment: I agree with Mike here.  The code the OP has looks to have been written as an exe with a standard Main entry point.  It would be more straight forward to modify it to use as a library. Also, if you use single quotes in your here string, you won't have to escape the double quotes inside it.  :-)